# Excel Web query: Unable to pass username and password to Windows security Login

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-web-query, vba

I am trying to automate few web queries for my company's website.

The website is password secured and everytime the excel is opened, it asks for the UID and pwd via the windows security pop-up.

Is there a way to pass the credentials to windows security login via VBA.

PS:
I tried to open a web browser,  connect to it and then run the

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("B2"))
```

with required query parameters. It is not helping.

The windows security login box still pops up.

Comment: maybe `http://username:password@example.com` http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: it works as a URL. But when passing the URL to the ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("B2")) , I get error.

Comment: What error? You might have to URL encode any special characters that are not letters or digits.

Comment: Hi all thanks for trying to help. I realized. it is tricky to automate the Login via Excel Web queries. Alternatively, I tried using Python to scrape data from the site, it was easy and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for trying to help. I realized. it is tricky to automate the Login via Excel Web queries. Alternatively, I tried using Python to scrape data from the site, it was easy and it worked.